# Interface Cast Type Safety

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

Type safety prevents unwanted casting during compile-type. How can one achieve the same **compile-time** type safety for inherited interfaces?

```
public interface IBase { }
public interface IFoo : IBase { }
public interface IBar { }


public class Base { }
public class Foo : Base { }
public class Bar { }

public class Test
{
    public void TestInterface()
    {
        IBase item = null;

        IFoo foo = item as IFoo;

        // How to get an error?
        IBar bar = item as IBar;
    }

    public void TestClass()
    {
        Base item = null;

        Foo foo = item as Foo;

        // Error since Bar is not derived from Base
        Bar bar = item as Bar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, and shouldn't - because it might not be an error. Consider an extra class:

```
class BarBase : IBase, IBar
{
}
```

Now:

```
IBase item = new BarBase();
IBar bar = item as IBar;
```

That will leave `bar` as a non-null reference - so why would you want it to be a compile-time error? Note that the compiler shouldn't/doesn't take notice of:

- How you actually initialized `item`
- Whether or not there happen to be any classes that implement `IBase` and `IBar`

It *will* take notice of whether such a conversion could ever be valid. Consider:

```
public sealed class Sealed {}
public interface IFoo {}

Sealed x = null;
IFoo foo = x as IFoo; // Error
```

Here there is *no* possible non-null value of `Sealed` that could implement `IFoo`, because there can't be any subclasses of `Sealed` implementing the interface... so the compiler gives an error.

Comment: What a subtle note `item as IBar`

Comment: @MohsenAfshin: I'm not sure what you mean... that code is just what's in your question.

Comment: in fact by your sealed example I understand the reason for allowing the conversion and not throwing any error can be this:`As while as an interface can be implemented by source object, the conversion of source to that interface is allowed`. Am I correct?

Comment: @MohsenAfshin: Yes - basically, if it's *feasible* that a conversion will succeed, the conversion is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The compiler doesn't know that the type that implements `IBase` and `IFoo` doesn't also implement `IBar`. It isn't class inheritance where it is impossible to derive from more than one.

What if `item` was an instance of this class?

```
public class BarAndFoo : IBar, IFoo { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance is not allowed in C#, so it is not possible that a class derived from `Base` can be cast to `Bar`.

However a class can implement several interfaces. So it is possible that an object referenced by `IBase` reference is an instance of a class that also implements `IBar`. In that case, the cast will be valid.

```
public class BarFoo : IBar, IFoo { }

IBase item = new BarFoo();
IFoo foo = item as IFoo;
IBar bar = item as IBar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiler will be able to throw an error if you try to compile the following code:

```
IFoo foo = null;
IBar bar = foo; // Invalid cast at compile-time
```

When you use `as` operator, you're telling the compiler to leave the cast *as is* and let the runtime determine if the cast is valid or not, and if it's not valid it sets `null`.

If you want compile-time errors for these situations you should take a look at [*Code Contracts*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx) and you can always use an assertion:

```
  IFoo foo = new Foo();
  IBar bar = foo as IBar;
  Contract.Assert(bar != null);
```

...and enable static contract checking and [Code Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx) compiler will throw warnings or errors depending on your project settings during compile-time:

> Code contracts include classes for marking your code, a static
>   analyzer for compile-time analysis, and a runtime analyzer. The
>   classes for code contracts can be found in the
>   System.Diagnostics.Contracts namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the `item` object can be a class that implements both interfaces (`IBase` and `IBar`) so that kind of cast is perfectly fine.

```
class MyImplementation : IBase, IFoo, IBar {
}

IBase x = new MyImplementation();
IBar bar = x as IBar; // valid
```